# Accessing dictionary in the array

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

I created a function CreateArrayOfDicts() which returns the array of dictionaries. Now I'm struggling with accessing the dictionary in the other sub. How is possible to access one of the dictionary, especially the values under the dedicated key in each dictionary?

> 'Category'

is one of the keys in the dictionary

```
 Sub EditDataSeriesParams()
    Dim mySeries As Series
    Dim key As Variant
    catparams = CreateArrayofDicts() ' array of dictionaries
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    i = 7
    'Debug.Print ws.Cells(7, 21)

    Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 21))
        For Each mySeries In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test").Chart.SeriesCollection
            For j = 0 To UBound(catparams) 'entering array of dictionaries
                If ws.Cells(i, 21) = mySeries.Name And catparams(j).("Category") = mySeries.Name Then ' issue is here
                    mySeries.Select
                    Debug.Print 5
                    With Selection
                        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleTriangle
                        .MarkerSize = catparams(j)("Size") ' Size is a key in dict
                        .MarkerBackgroundColor = catparams(j)("Back") ' Back is a key in dict
                        .MarkerForegroundColor = catparams(j)("Front") ' Front is a key in dict

                    End With

                End If

            Next j
        Next mySeries

    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `catparams`?

Comment: It is an array of dictionaries. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842393/adding-a-dictionary-to-array/61843474#61843474

Comment: It's literally the first line of your question haha. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the dot, as you've done subsequently in your code...

```
catparams(j)("Category") = mySeries.Name
```